# find javascript code that changes particular css properties

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug some styling issues on a site that has tons of .js files included. One of those scripts adds some css properties to an input element on click.

Is there an easy way to find which script and which part of it alters those css properties using Chrome Developer Tools?

Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116

Comment: can you share fiddle or any other link?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought a fiddle would help in this case as it's a very generic question... It would apply to any website that has js affecting css properties, right?

Comment: If the style added is unique enough, you may be able to search the codebase for some unique string from the style to significantly narrow your search, or even find the line outright. If the styles modify the inline `style` attribute on the element, you *might* also be able to get a dynamic breakpoint by right clicking the element in the dev tools `Elements` pane, and choosing `Break on...` > `Attributes Modification`. You might have to look up the call stack if it does hit the breakpoint to find your own code (as opposed to any potential library code responsible for the actual style change).

Comment: Bingo, "right clicking the element in the dev tools Elements pane, and choosing Break on... > Attributes Modification" is exactly what I was looking for... If you post that as an answer it will be accepted ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Elements panel, right-click the element in question, and in the context menu choose `Break on...` > `Attributes Modifications`. Next time its `style` attribute is changed, the debugger will break on the corresponding JS line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the developer tools to delete the element that changes on click. Then click the element that triggers the change. Since it can't be changed it will issue an error. The error will have a link on the right to show you exactly where it broke.

This should produce the exact file and function/script.

So say this is your element `<div class="bob">Apple</div>` and on click, Js adds `style="color:red;"` by deleting .bob you will break the script.

Note: Use developer tools to delete it. That way it doesn't permanently mess with your project.

Note2: Before deleting it, try just editing it and changing its id and/or class, like "xxbob", so it will no longer be recognized by the code.

Comment: It's possible this won't work. For instance, if the deleted target element is queried for in the handler (as opposed to, e.g., outside of it and using a closure for the handler to access it) in such a way that not finding it returns an empty node list, then there might not be an error, since the CSS change will just be acting on an empty node list and do nothing. It's still worth a try.

Comment: You're right, deleting the target element causes no error. Worth a try though.

Comment: Is it jquery? You could possibly remove the link to the jquery file, then triggering it would issue an error since it would have no function.